# I want to use Camera preview instead of an jpg file

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-viewholder

```
     mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inMutable=true;
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                R.drawable.test1,
                options
        );
```

This is the example code. I want to use my mTextureView which is holding a camera preview, Instead of test1.jpg file.
Please help me with this. I'm desperate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539139/example-of-camera-preview-using-surfacetexture-in-android

Comment: Do you want to get an image from `mTextureView` or what? It's not clear what do you want, I see a `mTextureView` and bitmap decoding code, they're not related as I see